# Python Selenium: Unable to locate element with id

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to select a button but I keep getting the error of:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="loginbutton"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
```

the id of the button is correct, not sure what i'm doing wrong.

I'm running this code

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless = False
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

def initializedBrowser():
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
time.sleep(3)
initializedBrowser()

emailelement = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
emailelement.send_keys("testing")

logginButton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginbutton')
logginButton.click()
```

But i see it exist here in this image
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "loginbutton"))).click()
```

You will also need the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element  you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#loginbutton[name='login']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='loginbutton' and @name='login']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```